# Python Bubble sort

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, time-limit-exceeded

```
a = [5, 2, 4, 6, 1, 3]

def insert(arr):
    if len(arr) == 1:
        return arr
    # outer loop
    for i in range(1, len(arr)): 
        # inner loop
        for j in range(i, 0, -1):
            if arr[j] < arr[j-1]:
                arr[j], arr[j-1] = arr[j-1], arr[j]
    return arr

print(insert(a))
```

I am getting a time out for this program implementing bubble sort.
Where is the problem and how can I optimize this?
My hunch is that it might be the inner loop, which loops through the list backward, but I can't seem to understand why it would take like 4.5s to sort the above list.

Comment: This doesn't look like [Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) to me. More like a type of bubblesort.

Comment: I agree with Gloweye, this looks like bubble sort and bubble sort is in fact one of the most inefficient sorting algorithms, so it's not unlikely to take some time sorting things

Comment: There is no reason to comment `# outer loop` and `# inner loop`. Anyone can see that for themselves. You really don't need comments for the obvious and the real goal is to write your code in a way that removes the need for comments by making the code readable. readability > shorter code. Of coarse there will be some cases where comments will be needed but for the most part you can avoid things like `# this loop does this thing` or `# setting up my variables and so on`.

Comment: If I run you exact code here, it runs quite fast. Fast enough for me to get the same timestamp before and after execution(python's `time.time()` - I dont bother with timeit for something like this). Could you sort this out and then edit that into the question ?

Comment: Why would you call a sorting function `insert`?

Comment: `why it would take like 4.5s to sort [5, 2, 4, 6, 1, 3]` How did you establish that timing? `getting a time out`/`getting a time out` where does the/a time limit come from?